# Using TJsonTextWriter inside TRESTRequest as a class member?

Tags: c++, c++builder

I am using the `TRESTRequest` object for **REST** API calls and want to clean up the code a bit more to make it more usable/readable.

The following is a simplified example of my category POST:

```
void clsAPI::createCategory(String name, int parentId)
{
    RestRequest->Body->ClearBody(); // Empties RestRequest->Body

    CustomJsonWriter->createCategory(RestRequest->Body->JSONWriter, name, parentId); // Pass the writer, to write the request

    executeOnResource(rmPOST, "categories"); // Send JSON to server
}
```

Now I want to change these calls:

from: `CustomJsonWriter->createCategory(RestRequest->Body->JSONWriter, name, parentId);`

to: `CustomJsonWriter->createCategory(name, parentId);`

and initialize my `CustomJsonWriter` with a pointer to `RestRequest->Body->JSONWriter`

```
void clsAPI::init() {
    CustomJsonWriter = new clsCustomJsonWriter(RestRequest->Body->JSONWriter);
}
```

The inside of the `createCategory()` function contains something along the lines of (after implementing the class member `TJsonTextWriter * Writer)`:

```
void clsCustomJsonWriter::createCategory(String name, int parentId)
{
    Writer->WriteStartObject();
    Writer->WritePropertyName("category");
    Writer->WriteStartObject();

    Writer->WritePropertyName("name");
    Writer->WriteValue(name);

    Writer->WritePropertyName("parent_id");
    Writer->WriteValue(parentId);

    Writer->WriteEndObject();
    Writer->WriteEndObject();
}
```

However, this makes my program freeze. Stepping through the debugger shows that the program freezes on `Writer->WriteStartObject()`. This didn't happen when I sent the `JSONWriter` as a parameter for the `createCategory()` function.

Is there a decent way to use the `RestRequest->Body->JSONWriter` as a class member for my own `CustomJsonWriter`? Or should I just keep passing the `JSONWriter` through each function?

**EDIT 1:**

I've tried using pointer to pointer on `RestRequest->Body->JSONWriter`, but I can't take the pointer address. using `&RestRequest->Body->JSONWriter`;

**EDIT 2:**

I have solved the problem, by using `CustomJsonWriter->setWriter(RestRequest->Body->JSONWriter);` and calling this function before each REST request.

**why?**

Through speculation/observation I found out the following: `JSONWriter` has a getter function, which initializes the object if empty, so that it can be written to. However, if a pointer to the initialized object has been acquired, the getter function will not be called, when accessing the object through the pointer.

This will lead to a NULL pointer after calling `RestRequest->Body->ClearBody()`. It seems that this function deletes the `JSONWriter` and leaves you with a dangling pointer.

Example:

```
TJSONWriter * pWriter = RestRequest->Body->JSONWriter; // Acquire a pointer
RestRequest->Body->ClearBody(); // RestRequest->Body->JSONWriter now becomes NULL

// Getter function will not be called from the pointer, so:
pWriter->Write("contents"); // Exception! pWriter points to NULL

pWriter = RestRequest->Body->JSONWriter; // Getter function is called, and initializes a new object/pointer to use.
```

Comment: You can't take the address of a property, especially if it uses a getter method. Did you check that the `JSONWriter` is ready and available at the time `init()` is called? Is it possible that `Writer` is being set to null? Or maybe the `JSONWriter` is being reset after `init()` has captured the previous `Writer`? I would suggest removing the `JSONWriter` from `init()`, and then expose a new method for `clsAPI::createCategory()` to call, eg: `CustomJsonWriter->setWriter(RestRequest->Body->JSONWriter); CustomJsonWriter->createCategory(name, parentId);`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know why I couldn't take the address, but now I do. The problem itself has been solved: It's the getter function of `RestRequest->Body->JSONWriter` that leaves me with a dangling pointer after `RestRequest->Body->ClearBody()`. My last edit will explain more